# exclusive parameter when using GetFile with Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am reading through the documentation on PhoneGap and I'm struggling to understand the point of the exclusive parameter when getting files.

So the documentation lists this as an example.

```
// Create the lock file, if and only if it doesn't exist.
lockFile = dataDir.getFile("lockfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true});
```

So what I'm struggling to get my head around is that surely it would only create "lockfile.txt" if the file doesn't exist anyway?

How is setting the exclusive parameter to be true make any difference? When would it be needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Different object literals and their differences

**Create is false:**

- Exclusive will be ignored.
- If the path exists the file will be returned.
- If the path doesn't exist an error is thrown. You will get error code 1 (NOT_FOUND_ERR).
- If the path exists, but it's a directory an error is thrown. You will get error code 11 (TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR).

**Create is true:**

- If exclusive is true and the path already exists an error is thrown. You will get error code 12 (PATH_EXISTS_ERR).
- If exclusive is false you will get no error when the path already exists. When the path doesn't exist a file will be created.

Everything I typed above is also visible in the image below.

[image: Different object literals and their differences]

#### How is setting the exclusive parameter to be true make any difference?

When create is false it will not make any difference. When create is true and if the file exists it will not be overwritten and you will get an error. You will get error code 12 (PATH_EXISTS_ERR).

#### When would it be needed?

Maybe you don't want your file to be overwritten.

#### Sources:

The image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry

Error codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError